# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I just installed the GoogleMaps framework to my Xcode proj using Cocoapods
and I got these errors when compiling

```
Warning:
Target 'Pods' of project 'Pods' was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'x86_64' didn't contain all required architectures 'i386 x86_64'
Error:
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help

Comment: Could you provide more information about your pod file, What you written in your pod file?

Comment: Its architecture issue. 
As verify with pods project and existing project that weather its with same architecture or not. 
Targets > Build Setting > Build Active architecture.